# javascript squared

Tags: javascript

What is better to use in javascript to square some value. 
Math.pow

```
Math.pow((circle2.x - circle1.x), 2)
```

Or my own function

```
square(circle2.x - circle1.x);

function square(a){
    return a*a;
}
```

Comment: Better in what sense?

Comment: what variant is working faster

Comment: You probably don't need to worry which one is working faster - there are probably better places for optimization than this one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is nearly always better to use a library then write your own code, unless you have a good reason not to.  Reasons why:

- It saves you work.
- It is well-tested code, while your code might introduce bugs.
- Someone else who looks at your code will know what `Math.pow` is, so it makes your code easier to read.

Obviously this is a very simple case, in which your own function is unlikely to cause a problem.  Still, it is better to get in the habit of using libraries whenever possible.

By the way, `Math.pow` performs [a lot of handling of special cases](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-math.pow).  This illustrates that even a simple function can have more pitfalls than it appears at first.  By using a library, you don't have to worry about handling all of the edge cases yourself.

Comment: ✢1 Great tips. ⎯1 Woah woah woah. This is JavaScript, not Java!

Comment: @wizzwizz4, whoops: good catch!  I have fixed the link to point to JS information.

Comment: isn't it Math.pow not math.Pow?

Comment: @Julix thanks for catching the typo.

Answer (score 2):

You should always prefer to use library functions - what is the point in reinventing the wheel?
Library functions are optimized and may cater for some corner cases you are not aware of...

Are you going to provide own implementation of multiplication as well?

Answer (score 1):

For a power 2 specifically I would use multiplication because you really don't lose any legibility. Even more if speed is important, multiplying will probably be faster than function calls.
edit: I mean don't even create a function... just a*a.